# ruby inheritence failure I can't undertand

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I can't understand why the following code give error

```
./nodes.rb:14:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from ./nodes.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from ./nodes.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from ./nodes.rb:31:in `new'
    from ./nodes.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

Can someone please enlighten me?

```
class Base 
  def initalize(msg)
    print "########## This is the Base class ###########"
  end
end

class A < Base
  attr_accessor :var_a
  def initialize(msg)
    super
    var_a = "AAAAA"
    print "########### From A: #{msg}  VAR: #{var_a} ########################\n"
  end
end

class B < A
  attr_accessor :var_b
  def initialize(msg)
    super
    var_b = "BBBBB"
    print "########### From B: #{msg}  VAR: #{var_b} ########################\n"
    binding.pry
  end
end

b = B.new("test")
no = A.new("This is 'A'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled `initialize` wrong in `Base`. So, the `super` call in `A` refers to the default `Object#initialize` which doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The other posters are correct that you spelled "initialize" wrong in your code.

Something to be aware of when using super in ruby - when calling "super" by itself it will pass all arguments given to the current method. So in your case it was passing msg to a new Base class. Because you spelled initialize wrong, it wouldn't accept any arguments hence why you were getting a (1 for 0) error.

If you kept your current code and used super() it would call the super method without any arguments, and work. Albeit with the error, but this would be able to run. Using super with the empty parenthesis is one of the only time I can think of where this will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in:

```
class Base 
  def initalize(msg)
```

It should be `initialize`. So Ruby uses the default `initialize` that takes no argument, causing the `ArgumentError` you saw.

Comment: thanks!  now I feel silliy

Answer (score -2):

`super` invokes a method with the same name as the current method in the superclass of the current class.  It is invoking `initialize` in each of the parent classes and needs a `msg`.

Comment: The error message says the exact opposite: it says that an argument was passed were none was expected, not the other way round.

Comment: Actually it doesn't need a msg because it was mistyped.